# PS4 controller won't connect even on safe mode

Tags: controllers, ps4

My controller just blinks white once and doesn't connect ): even when its plugged in..

I tried:

- 2 different controllers
- a different USB cable
- turned off the ps4 and tried turning it on with the controller
- resetting it with the button in the back and the share/psn button
- tried connecting with it through safe-mode

Comment: I had the same problem and I fixed it by leaving it off and charging it for a while (Initially thought it was a battery problem) then I connected it to my Uncle's ps4 and the used it to switch his ps4 on (Connecting the device to another ps4). AFter this I repeated the previous step on my own ps4 and it worked.